# Is there a mouse that supports tapping as a left click?

Tags: magic-trackpad, click, mouse-keys

I am looking for more movement leeway and thinking of using a mouse with my MacBook. But physically pressing a mouse key to left click is not that nice an experience after the trackpad. Is there a macOS supporting mouse that accepts tapping as a left click on it (just like in the trackpad)? Would the upcoming magic mouse models support this feature?

Comment: I don't like tapping to left-click. On trackpad it is far slower than simply a pressure click, and more prone to misclicks, and on a mouse you have to levitate your finger? Either constantly or just before clicking. Either way it forces a larger and more tedious range of motion, more conducive to rsi, and is also more prone to misclicks.

Answer (score 0):

There is software called [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) that allows you to customise input devices, including to add "tap to click" to a MacBook Trackpad or Magic Mouse.